# Check for similarity in string using Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I cannot disclose the actual data so I am just using an example. I have two tables one is a dictionary table which has the IDs for the titles. The second table is new data that's coming into the database and doesn't have IDs I need to update the ID for the new data by checking in the dictionary table if I have something similar already in there or else update the dictionary with the new value and get a new ID for it and update the same for the new data. The `Expected ID` column in the second table is what I expect them to be updated as.

```
ID  Title

--  ------------------------

1   Aliens
2   The Hunger Games
3   John Wick
4   Alien vs Predator



ID  Title                                         Expected ID

----------------------------------------------------------------

null   The Hunger Games: Mockingjay Part I        2
null   The Hunger Games: Mockingjay Part II       2
null   John Wick (2014)                           3
null   John Wick Chapter 2                        3
null   Alien                                      1
null   Aliens                                     1
null   Alien 3                                    1
null   Lord of the Rings                          5 (New ID generated)
```

Comment: How much data do you have?  Such comparisons can be very expensive.  If you have a lot of rows, then you don't only want the logic for the match but a mechanism for doing it in human time frames.

Comment: @GordonLinoff The new data comes in every week so batches of 300-400 records. The dictionary probably has 20000 records but sure need to have an efficient query because we have a lot of other processes that keep running in the background.

Comment: whatis the query so far?

Comment: I haven't been able to come up with one yet @Gauravsa

Comment: You discuss two input tables, but only show an example of one input table.  We can kind of guess maybe what belongs in 2nd input table based on the output, but don't make us guess.  Also, what is the point of the all-NULL column in the output?

Comment: @jjanes I have shown both the input tables. The table you see on top of the question is the dictionary table (this table has more columns that are not important to the question). The one on the bottom is the second table which gets its data from a file and hence the ID column is null and that column needs to be updated. And as mentioned in the question the Expected ID column in the bottom table is what I expect the values in ID column to be and that column doesn't actually exist.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a task for [pg_trgm](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgtrgm.html).  It provides you with the `%` operator, which returns true if the two strings are "close enough".  You can tune what close enough means via changing pg_trgm.similarity_threshold.  You can create an index to accelerate this operation.  The higher similarity_threshold is set, the more acceleration you are likely to achieve.

If I take you first shown table as foo1 and all the distinct titles from your desired output as foo2, then this query gives reasonable results:

```
select *, foo1.title <-> foo2.title as distance from foo2 left join foo1 on foo1.title % foo2.title;

                title                 |   id   |       title       | distance  
--------------------------------------+--------+-------------------+-----------
 The Hunger Games: Mockingjay Part I  |      2 | The Hunger Games  | 0.5142857
 The Hunger Games: Mockingjay Part II |      2 | The Hunger Games  | 0.5277778
 John Wick (2014)                     |      3 | John Wick         | 0.3333333
 John Wick Chapter 2                  |      3 | John Wick         |       0.5
 Alien                                |      1 | Aliens            |     0.375
 Alien                                |      4 | Alien vs Predator | 0.6666666
 Aliens                               |      1 | Aliens            |         0
 Alien 3                              |      1 | Aliens            |       0.5
 Alien 3                              |      4 | Alien vs Predator |       0.7
 Lord of the Rings                    | (null) | (null)            |    (null)
```

If you want one a single output row for each foo2, showing the "best" match only, then you would use a LEFT JOIN LATERAL:

```
select *, a.title <-> foo2.title as distance from foo2 left join lateral 
    (select * from foo1 where foo1.title % foo2.title order by foo1.title <-> foo2.title limit 1) a
    on true;
                title                 |   id   |      title       | distance  
--------------------------------------+--------+------------------+-----------
 The Hunger Games: Mockingjay Part I  |      2 | The Hunger Games | 0.5142857
 The Hunger Games: Mockingjay Part II |      2 | The Hunger Games | 0.5277778
 John Wick (2014)                     |      3 | John Wick        | 0.3333333
 John Wick Chapter 2                  |      3 | John Wick        |       0.5
 Alien                                |      1 | Aliens           |     0.375
 Aliens                               |      1 | Aliens           |         0
 Alien 3                              |      1 | Aliens           |       0.5
 Lord of the Rings                    | (null) | (null)           |    (null)
```

How to replace the NULL in the "id" column (where there are no close-enough matches) with a newly generated id is a separate question, and you should ask separate questions separately.

For any realistically sized datasets, it is unlikely you would be able to just blindly accept whatever a query like the above produces, at least not if you want high quality results.  Rather, you could have the computer generate something like the above as recommendations, and then offer them (in a convenient interface) for a human to ratify, reject, or investigate further.